# How much calcium nitrate should I add to 32 fl. oz. of water?

Tags: fertilizer, nutrients

I have some prilled Greenway Biotech calcium nitrate (15.5% nitrogen; 19% calcium) that I want to put in a 32 fluid ounce spray bottle to spray on the leaves of pepper and tomato plants, and such.

If I fill the spray bottle with water, how much calcium nitrate should I add before spraying the plants (assuming they're in need of nitrogen and calcium)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it looks like the answer is actually on the website I got it from, sans the math. I just missed it, I guess.

Anyway, the answer, according to the website, would be a half tablespoon to one tablespoon per 32 fluid ounces of water (for a foliar spray): They said 2-4 tablespoons per gallon of water.

Edit: So, now that I'm using a [51oz, or 1500ML, sprayer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00002N8OB) (advertised as 48oz), I need to add about a tablespoonful (more or less--probably less, for houseplants, based on my observations; not sure about vegetables).